# html5 cropping an image drawn on canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a timer in a canvas game using an image which I want to crop from the top to show time counting down.

I know I need to use this:

```
          ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
```

But I just can't get my head around it, I've been looking at a few sites but their explanation doesn't seem to register with me.

The below sorta works to reduce height, as I have a variable counting down to reduce the height, I just need to use that to crop the height instead of reduce it:

```
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,80,heightVar);
```

Can anyone please tell me how to draw this image at 0,0, it's width is 80px and height 480px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, you'll want to do something like this:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 480 - heightVar, 80, heightVar,
                   0, 480 - heightVar, 80, heightVar);
```

That's gonna make the image appear at 0, 0 when the gauge is full (heightVar = 480) and crop it from the top down as heightVar increases. I hope this helps you.

You're also going to want to make sure that heightVar stays in the (0 - 480) interval. Otherwise, ghosts may appear.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've been fiddling with it since you posted. It doesn't crop down for me. Changing things around I can get it to grow from the top or bottom. Any ideas?

Comment: I must have misunderstood the way you want your timer gauge to work, then. Isn't this what you wanted? http://eldersatplay.com/gauge/

Threw together a quick test of it and it works as I intended it. How did you mean for it to work?

Comment: I'm just letting the "heightVar" get modulated by time there, to illustrate how it looks for different values.

Comment: thats exactly how I wanted it. Thanks for the example, I'm clearly doing something silly.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: it's working now, thanks. I mistakenly commented out a line which was clearing that area of the canvas before redrawing the image, which is why I was only noticing the image 'growing' from the top or bottom. The cropping from the top code you gave was perfect, but I couldn't see that as it was drawing on top of itself. I really appreciate the help and the example.